# Using striped tabs without header ionic

Tags: javascript, css, tabs, ionic-framework

I'm using striped tabs without header, and i'm having this blank space between tabs and content.

so I want to know if I can override the ion-view css, and to fix this blank space.

[image]

here is my code :

[CODEPEN CODE + DEMO](http://codepen.io/stranger90/pen/MwjGPY)

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-striped tabs-top tabs-background-dark tabs-color-energized">

        <ion-tab title="hier"ui-sref="help">
           <ion-nav-view name="help"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <ion-tab title="aujourd'hui" ui-sref="home">
            <ion-nav-view name="home"> </ion-nav-view> 
        </ion-tab>

 <ion-tab title="demain" ui-sref="contact">
            <ion-nav-view name="contact"></ion-nav-view> 
        </ion-tab>



    </ion-tabs>
```

i'm using this css code to put the striped bar up :

```
.tabs-top >.tabs, .tabs.tabs-top
{
    top: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.has-tabs-top {
  top: 50px!important;
}
```

You should play with the value to match your needs.